# Ext JS gridpanel's word wrapping doesn't work well with renderer

Tags: extjs

I'm using `wordWrap` config for grid columns and version of EXT JS I'm using is `6.5.3`:

```
{
    dataIndex: "header",
    menuDisabled: true, 
    sortable: false,
    cellWrap: true,
    renderer: myRenderer
}
```

The problem with it is that the grid renderer seems to affect cells individually so the whole grid is not consistently rendered when there are word-wrapped cells and regular cells at the same time:

Inconsistently Rendered Grid

[image: Inconsistently Rendered Grid]

What I want to achieve is like:

Consistenly Rendered Grid

[image: Consistenly Rendered Grid]

Does anyone have any solution to fix it?
I'd appreciate some help : )

I have no idea how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add css to grid cells common class

text-overflow: ellipsis;

Comment: Hi, Vikas, thanks for your answer but it doesn't work in my case... Border lines still are fixed to where they were before and not even adjusting themselves.